# Setting WinRAR to exclude files with the exact filename I specify from being extracted from an archive

Tags: windows-7, zip, extract, 7-zip, winrar

How can I configure WinRAR to exclude files with the exact filenames: `thumbs.db` or `.DS_Store` (ignoring case) from being extracted from an archive (all directory levels within an archive)?

Files with these filenames *should not* be extracted:

```
Thumbs.db
thumbs.db
THUMBS.DB
.DS_Store 
.ds_store
.DS_STORE
```

Files with these names *should* be extracted:

```
1Thumbs.db
1thumbs.db
tackthumbs.db
Thumbs.db.txt
Abcd thumbs.db.txt
1.DS_Store
Abcd.ds_store
.DS_Store.txt
Abcd.DS_STORE.txt
```

Also, does anyone know if WinRAR has a syntax guide for the prohibited file types list in case I'd like to add more filenames or be flexible with the rules I need?

Essentially I'd like to avoid extracting unnecessary files from ZIP, RAR or 7z archives in Windows 7 - files like Windows 2000/XP's [Thumbs.db file (Thumbnail cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache)) and Mac OS X' [.DS_Store file (Desktop Services Store)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store), while not being too strict and also not extracting files which just contain 'Thumbs.db' or '.DS_Store' in its filename.

Edit:
I've entered `thumbs.db .DS_Store` in the WinRAR prohibited file list. I have encountered a ZIP file that has a .DS_Store file in a 2nd level directory. `(Zipfile.zip > Parent Directory > Directory where .DS_Store is stored)`. When I extract this ZIP file, WinRAR still extracts the .DS_Store file. Changing `.DS_Store` to `*.DS_Store` in the prohibited files list fixes this. The same issue happens with thumbs.db files.

My prohibited files list is now `*thumbs.db *.DS_Store`, while this could exclude `*thumbs.db` and `*.DS_Store` in all directories, my concern is that this could also affect filenames that I do not intend to exclude (e.g. `SampleThumbs.db` or `Sample.DS_Store`).

Anyone know why the previous entry didn't work in non-root directories in this case?  Also, is there a better entry in the Prohibited files list that will work to exclude *only* thumbs.db and .DS_Store files for *all directory levels* in a ZIP/RAR/7z file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work exactly like that. I created a test folder containing the following files:

- `DONOTHING.txt`
- `THUMBS.db`
- `.DS_STORE`
- `1Thumbs.db`
- `Thumbs.db.txt`

I then added these to a new RAR archive and configured the *Prohibited file types* dialogue as per the following screenshot:

[image: Prohibited file types]

The defaults were a set of wildcarded file extensions so I didn't think having full filenames would work, but tried anyway. I opened the previously created archive file and extracted it. The following files were extracted:

- `DONOTHING.txt`
- `1Thumbs.db`
- `Thumbs.db.txt`

It worked as you were expecting, and ignored the case of the file names.

I couldn't find a definitive guide to the syntax that should be used for the *Prohibited file types* field but this is from the manual:

> File types to exclude from extracting
>   If you enable this option, you can
>   specify the list of potentially
>   dangerous file masks in input field
>   below. It is allowed to enter several
>   masks separated by spaces. WinRAR will
>   skip files matching any of these masks
>   when extracting or opening archived
>   files.
>
> This option may help to protect users
>   from infected email attachments. For
>   example, if you enter:
>
> *.scr *.pif *.exe
>
> in this field, it will prohibit users
>   to unpack, view and run .scr, .pif and
>   .exe files with WinRAR.

In simple terms, if you separate each excluded file name/ file type with a space then you should have a working list of case insensitive files to skip on archive extraction.

Comment: I've entered `thumbs.db .DS_Store` in the prohibited file list. I have encountered a ZIP file that has a .DS_Store file in a 2nd level directory. (`Zipfile.zip > Parent Directory > Directory where .DS_Store is stored`). When I extract this ZIP file, WinRAR still extracts the .DS_Store file. Changing `.DS_Store` to `*.DS_Store` fixes this. My prohibited files list is now `thumbs.db *.DS_Store`. Anyone know why the previous entry didn't work in this case?

Comment: I got this email from WinRAR support answering my question in the above comment: *"If file mask does not contain wildcard characters and does not contain path, it is valid only for root archive folder."*

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern

```
*/Thumbs.db
```

and in specific case of *.DS_Store - you might need to enter the pattern

```
*.DS_Store
```

, because there could be files named ".DS_Store" and "._.DS_Store".